# Pytest-pep8: Deprecation Error from the Head First Python 2'nd edition

Tags: python, pytest, pep8

I have been following code from Python Head first 2nd edition in chapter 4. Here is the code:

```
def search4vowels(phrase:str) -> set: #set - lots of
    """Returns the vowels found in the specified word."""
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    return vowels.intersection(set(phrase))

def search4letters(phrase:str, letters:str='aeiou') -> set:
    """Returns the set of letters from 'letters' found in the specified line"""
    return set(letters).intersection(set(phrase))
```

> *the above snippet had comments in Russian that were translated into english*

and then I wrote with instructions in cmd:

```
> py.test --pep8 vsearch.py


Output:

================== test session starts ==========================

platform win32 -- Python 3.10.0, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\nikit\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\School\Книги\Python\PYfiles
plugins: pep8-1.0.6
collected 0 items / 1 error

================== ERRORS =======================================

__________________ ERROR collecting test session ________________

Direct construction of Pep8Item has been deprecated, please use Pep8Item.from_parent.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#node-construction-changed-to-node-from-parent
for more details.
================== short test summary info ======================

ERROR
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!

================== 1 error in 0.15s =============================
```

What could cause this?

Comment: This looks like a tool is a bit out of sync.  You're using the very latest Python with a book that's about 5 years old.  The `--pep8` thing is just a style-checker.  For now I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Is that actually your code, or is your actual code properly indented?

Comment: `pytest-pep8` has not been maintained for 7 years. You should use one of the other PEP8 checkers available.

Answer (score 0):

Use pycodestyle instead https://pypi.org/project/pycodestyle/

```
pip install pep8
pep8 --first optparse.py
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Your answer could be improved by explaining why you recommend pycodestyle, and why pep8 will not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34538722)